# How to use names with spaces in MongoDB expressions?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In an example of using $size opration, authors cunningly avoided spaces:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC1", "description" : "product 1", colors: [ "blue", "black", "red" ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "ABC2", "description" : "product 2", colors: [ "purple" ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "item" : "XYZ1", "description" : "product 3", colors: [ ] }
```

Note that all fields are in quotes and only colors are by happy coincidence are not :)

But what if we had:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC1", "description" : "product 1", "true colors": [ "blue", "black", "red" ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "ABC2", "description" : "product 2", "true colors": [ "purple" ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "item" : "XYZ1", "description" : "product 3", "true colors": [ ] }
```

How would we write the query:

```
numberOfColors: { $size: "$colors" }
```

**UPDATE**

I found that

```
numberOfColors: { $size: "$true colors" }
```

just works. But what about "dot notation"? How would I refer nested objects inside such fields?

Comment: Same way. `$size: "$all colors.true colors"` should work if your `true colors` is a property of `all colors`.

Answer (score 0):

As Alex mentioned in the comment, given the documents as below with nested objects

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC1", "description" : "product 1", 
      "all colors" : { "true colors" : [ "blue", "black", "red" ] } }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "ABC2", "description" : "product 2", 
      "all colors" : { "true colors" : [ "purple" ] } }
```

The query could be

```
db.sp.aggregate([
    {$project: {item: 1, numberOfColor: {$size: '$all colors.true colors'}}}
]);
```

Result is

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC1", "numberOfColor" : 3 }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "ABC2", "numberOfColor" : 1 }
```